# Python + lighttpd + CGI: any web frameworks?

Tags: python, cgi, lighttpd, web-frameworks

I'm stuck with this server without root access. It has Python 2.6.5 and runs lighttpd, serving all Python scripts under CGI. Yes, plain old CGI. Unfortunately, I have to use this server only, so switching to more adequate hosting is not an option. So, my question is: are there any web frameworks for Python that I can use under these circumstances? I tried Django, web.py and Flask without any success besides HTTP 500 error, but maybe I'm just missing something.

Again, the requirements are:

- Python 2.6.5
- lighttpd
- plain old CGI
- no root access

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Some brilliant lad managed to make it work on a virtualenv through mod_cgi](http://joemaller.com/1467/django-via-cgi-on-shared-hosting/). You need some [CGI-WSGI bridge](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/2407/django.cgi) between `mod_cgi` and your Django project (which is really a WSGI application). There are a few things to adapt, for example, if you are using a `virtualenv` (which I highly suggest that you do).

The script is well thought-out, but I guess there's still the possibility that `request.FILES` might get mishandled. I hope you are not using file uploads. Also, please note that performance will be degraded while using CGI because your whole application is reloaded for every request. Using FastCGI or plain WSGI, multiple instances of your project can be started before actually serving requests, and every instance can process multiple requests during their lifetime (one at a time). This allows you to have a much faster load time as everything is still preloaded from the previous request.

Note also that it could be possible to replicate that functionality in the `.cgi` file: you could start multiple instances of your app and write to their socket, using `random.random` rotation for load balancing.

Comment: So to finally answer your question: yes, basically any Python framework can work with CGI using some bridge. Will it work reliably? I don't know. Will it offer good performance? Probably not.

Comment: lighttpd.conf at the server has the following line: `cgi.assign = ( ".py" => "/usr/bin/python" )` Looks like any virtualenv and shebang change won't help since lighttpd will always try to launch my scripts under regular Python interpreter. I did everything in that instruction and still getting a 500 error. Also lighttpd does not support any local .htaccess files.

Comment: Yeah, `.htaccess` files are only compatible with Apache. Do you have any error logs apart from that 500 error? The issue might be related to URL rewriting, which is mostly what the htaccess file tries to fix.

URL rewriting is a technique for web servers to reprocess a request after manipulating parts of it. You might still be able to acess your app through //example.com/yourwsgi.(py|cgi)/your/request/path/?foo=bar

Comment: Wikipedia for example uses rewriting for pretty links: `/wiki/Main_Page` is processed and rewritten internally to `/w/index.php?title=Main_Page`. Most rewrite engines allow for pretty impressive stuff, but you might be stuck with passing all your requests to your CGI script since you do not have permissions to configure it.

Comment: There's nothing relevant in the error log, strangely. And I got all my 500 errors when I accessed the script directly by its .py URL. I did not attempt any URL rewriting, since I cannot modify lighttpd.conf.

Comment: Are you able to run the simplest of CGI scripts under Python? Something like a script that only contains plain `print` statements, to see if it will run...

Comment: Yes, surely. I checked that in the first place, and simple scripts run without any problems. I can even launch executables from my home directory via the `subprocess` module.